# get return value from .exe file to xulrunner

Tags: c++, mfc, xulrunner

I have a .exe MFC file that i want to call it with xulrunner .i use from launch command but i can't return value from .exe file .

can anybody help me how i can do it ?

```
    var file = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"]
        .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile);

    var filePath =Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/directory_service;1"]
            .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIProperties)
            .get("AChrom", Components.interfaces.nsIFile).parent;

    file.initWithPath("file.exe");
    file.launch();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want return value use 'nsIProcess' :

```
var file = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"]
                     .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIFile);
file.initWithPath("c:\\myapp.exe");
var process = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/process/util;1"]
                        .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIProcess);
process.init(file);
var args = ["argument1", "argument2"];
process.run(true, args, args.length);
var retVal=process.exitValue;
```